# Parallels Tools causing Windows 10 to not initialize hard drives

Tags: macos, windows-10, virtual-machine, multi-boot, parallels

Currently I am dual EFI booting Windows 10 and OS X El Capitan on 2 separate SSD's.
I also have 2 separate HDD's. One is formatted NTFS, and one is formatted NTFS, and HFS in 2 separate partitions.

Using Windows 10 in Parallels works perfect after installing Parallels Tools. It works just as if I had an iMac with Windows 10 installed under BootCamp. No problems what so ever starting the virtual machine, and performance is great.
The problem is, once I decide to boot back into Windows 10 the 2 separate HDD's are not properly initialized in Windows 10 until I uninstall Parallels Tools. Device manager properly recognizes them but throws an error and says they can not be properly initialized.

I pinned the problem down to Parallels Tools because once I uninstall it, and restart Windows 10, everything works as normal. This is still usable, as I can just install Parallels Tools every time I boot my Windows 10 install as a virtual machine in Parallels, and then if I want to boot directly into Windows 10 I can uninstall Parallels Tools, and reboot again and I'm back to normal, but I would like to know if anyone has any suggestions or experience with this and if there is a fix.
It would be nice if I didn't have to install and uninstall Parallels Tools everytime.

Comment: Are you shutting down the VM before rebooting into it as Boot Camp? Also, are you using Parallels 11? Earlier versions have issues on El Cap.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, properly shutting down the machine each time, and I am using Parallels 11.